# Git checkout old commit as new one

Tags: git, rollback

Lets say I have 5 commits in Git

> asd324
>   qwe435
>   lkj456
>   uit677

My `HEAD` is currently at `asd324`

But I want to go back to `lkj456` without `Reset --hard`.

My need is, I want to make a new commit which will contain the codes of `lkj456` but will have its own commit log eg: `tre344`

I did `git checkout lkj456` but this created conflict with my remote repository.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can revert commits `asd324` and `qwe435`,

```
git revert asd324
git revert qwe435
```

This will create 2 commits that undo the changes from your original 2 commits. When you push this to your remote repository, it will be allowed.